# How can I keep the windshield frame in place?

Tags: honda, accord, windshield

I have a 97 Accord and part of the windshield frame (or maybe it's called "rubber trim") along the passenger side has come loose, as seen in this photo:

[image]

I took my car to the dealer, and they said they don't fix windshield frames.  They said I would need to take it to a windshield shop and have the entire windshield replaced.

Is there any way for me to get the frame to stay in place without needing to replace the entire windshield?  Preferably something that won't cause a problem in case I ever do decide to replace the windshield.

Comment: What is the make/model/year of your vehicle? I'm not sure I know exactly what you are talking about here, but would bet any body/windshield shop should be able to fix this for you without issue.

Answer (score 3):

As seen in the following diagram, your windshield lateral trim is basically a long deflector that is held in place by several clips.

[image: Honda Accord 1997 windshield trim. Image credit: hondapartsnow.com (http://www.hondapartsnow.com/parts-list/1997-honda-accord-4dr_lx_abs-ka-4at/front-windshield.html)]

Image source: Hondapartsnow, http://www.hondapartsnow.com/parts-list/1997-honda-accord-4dr_lx_abs-ka-4at/front-windshield.html

Assembly #7 serves to deflect airflow, and probably can simply be taken off. Your car will just make more wind noise. I would take it off, specifically so that parts do not come off at speed (and perhaps distract other users and cause an accident).

On the other hand, part 5 in the diagram looks to be the rubber bit that actually holds the glass in place, providing a seal to avoid water coming in.

As noted by @Paulster2, a windshield repair shop (or repair person) will probably be well able either to replace this trim, or take it off and confirm it is not really necessary. This is obviously easier to diagnose with the vehicle in front of you, than over the Internet.

Hope this helps.